# MySQL #1054 - Unknown column 'foo.column1' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I am getting a

> #1054 - Unknown column 'foo2.column2' in 'where clause'

for the following query.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS 
SELECT * FROM foo1 
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM  foo1 
WHERE foo1.column1= foo2.column2)
```

The column foo2.column2 exists since I can access it through through other queries.

Comment: did you mean to write `from foo2` in the sub-select?

Comment: You don't declare a foo2 in any FROM clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written foo1 again instead of foo2, in the subquery.
And also, I would recommend using join query instead, for the `SELECT` like below.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS 
SELECT * FROM foo1 JOIN foo2 ON foo1.column1= foo2.column2
```

Answer (score 0):

You **`didn't provide foo2 table in FROM Clause of your query`**. It should be **`foo2 instead of foo1`** in inner most sub query place.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS 
SELECT * FROM foo1 
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM  foo2 
WHERE foo1.column1= foo2.column2)
```